# Eloquent - Two Relationships In One?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've been getting along slowly but surely with Laravel / Eloquent, but am now stumped:

entries Table:

```
id
user_id
group_id
content
```

users Table

```
id
faculty_id
name
```

group Table:

```
id
name
```

faculty Table

```
id
name
```

So entries are related to users and groups, and users are related to faculties - I've set up the basic relationships without a problem, and this enables me to find all entries by users from a certain faculty:

Faculty Model:

```
public function entries()
{
return $this->hasManyThrough('Entry','User');
}
```

Controller:

```
Faculty::find(Faculty-ID-here)->entries;
```

However, I now need to find entries by users that are from a certain faculty AND from a certain group, and I don't know how to write this combination this in Eloquent.

Hope that makes sense! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Entries::whereHas('user', function($q) {
            $q->where('faculty_id', $facultyID);
        })
        ->where('group_id', $groupID)
        ->get();
```

Assuming you have set up your 'user' relationship.

Comment: Thank you so much! Learning new things about Laravel queries all the time